# How to detect and identify encoded characters

Tags: php, character-encoding

How would I go about detecting and identifying these types of characters(0xB0) while reading an unknown text file in php?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing all that fancy about it, you can use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) just like with any other character.

#### Example:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
RC\t"Active array size: 640
RC\t"58° viewing angle
TEXT;

var_dump(strpos($text, "\xB0") !== false);
```

#### Output:

```
bool(true)
```

---

<sub>*`"\xB0"` is just another way of saying `°`.*</sub>